# How to convert pages with a specific language in desktop version of my site (WordPress) to AMP version?

Tags: wordpress

I had i quiastion how i can redirect my DESKTOP pages on one language (i had 10 different languages on site) to AMP version? Users of a certain country are more likely to use phones for my site (70%)

I'm not competent enough to understand this issue